# Check if all functions from a header file are implemented in c file before linking

Tags: c, compilation

Is there a way to check if all functions from a header file are implemented **before linking**?

example:

### example.h

```
#include<stdio.h>

int function1(void);
int function2(void);
int function3(void);
```

### example.c

```
#include "example.h"

int function1(void)
{
    printf("Hi. I am function 1\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm looking for something that when compiling returns a warning like **"function2 and function3 are not implemented"**.

It it possible?

Thanks

Comment: search in the file

Comment: Not sure if it is doable by some directives, but it probably not. Consider to search in the file like suggested by Let Us Embed

Comment: Well the linker does it, so yes it is possible.  But why write another linker?

Comment: BTW: The linker does *not* check wether everything that is *offered* in the header is actually implemented - In most cases it will only check that what  is actually *called* by some other module is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You could try taking a look at an application called Splint which in section 7.3 of the documentation talks about declaration consistency such as '...checks that function declarations and definitions are consistent.' [http://www.splint.org]
I am not familiar with the application myself, but worth a look I would say.